# Error with Populated Table View

Tags: ios

I made a populated `tableView`, but I am getting this error from a line of code:

```
ViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

> Thread 1 : SIGABRT

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT can be caused by a number of different things. You can find out more information about the exact error by checking the console when the error occurs.

However, I would recommend checking the following:

1. `ViewCell` should probably be `UITableViewCell`, unless `ViewCell` is a subclass you have made yourself.
2. `Cellidentifier` needs to be an `NSString` which matches the 'Identifier' given to the cell in the storyboard or xib.